# app_global.asax.dll not generated in filesystem while publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, publish, global-asax, compiled

When I publish MVC application in filesystem, it published successfully. When I dumped into server and tried testing the code it is giving the error.
App_global.asax.dll is not present.

I tried below links, it didn't help:
        I don't want to precompile code while publishing.
        1. [App_Global.asax.compiled and App_Global.asax.dll missing? WebApi .NET 4.5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813759/app-global-asax-compiled-and-app-global-asax-dll-missing-webapi-net-4-5-projec) 
        2. [Global.asax not firing for Release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811005/global-asax-not-firing-for-release-build)
        3. [global.asax works on local computer but not after i publish to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647556/global-asax-works-on-local-computer-but-not-after-i-publish-to-server)
        The publish settings are as below : [image: Only Delete all existing files prior to publish is checked.]